# Vuejs 2 Data Binding Failed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I don't understand why it's not working and this driving me crazy

```html
<template>
    <p>{{ greeting }}</p>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'App',
        data: function(){
          return {
            greeting: 'this is message'
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Why `{{ greeting }}` not working ? It should be run the text. But I got this error

> Errors compiling template:
>
> Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure you don't have anything else in your `<template>`?

Comment: Could you share your `main.js` file located in the `src` folder? The problem might be in the render function there and not in your App component.

Comment: As per the error message you are having multiple element in root. but the file you have shared is having only one root element so please provide more details as asked above

Comment: i found after <template> need to wrap another <div> to make it work. Take few hours to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `<div>` with an  id `app` inside your `<template>` tag

```
<template>
    <div id="app">{{greeting}}</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "App",
    data: function() {
    return {
      greeting: "this is message"
    };
   }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: I found out this issue too. After wrapped with <div> only works. It should mention in documentation though.